# React Localize Global Styles?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, frontend

Is it possible to localize the global styles of a module to only one file?

for instance, I would like to change the width of an item from a react module but only for one file. *inline styles aren't possible :/*

edit for context: in my particular case ... i'm using 'react-multi-carousel' ... and to go over the breakpoint behavior, I've set  `.react-multi-carousel-item { width: 310px !important; }` . However i'd like this style to be applied only to one component and not my entire project (I'm using the carousel in more than one place). Any way to localize a global style (CSS file)?

Comment: i think this question needs a bit of elaboration, and perhaps an example

Comment: in my particular case ... i'm using 'react-multi-carousel' ... and to go over the breakpoint behavior, I've set ` .react-multi-carousel-item { width: 310px !important; }` . However i'd like this style to be applied only to one component and not my entire project (I'm using the carousel in more than one place). Any way to localize a global style (CSS file)?

Comment: are you using css modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just nest the CSS rule to only apply when inside a specific container:

```
.my-container .react-multi-carousel-item { width: 310px !important; }
```

And then in React:

```
return <>
  <MultiCarousel />
  <div className="my-container">
    <MultiCarousel />
  </div>
</>
```

In that example the first `<MultiCarousel />` would not see the extra style, but the second one would.

---

> "is there any way to add css within the TSX file by any chance? If possible, I'd like to not have an external css file."

You could try [a scoped style tag](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/)

For example:

```
return <>
  <div>
    <style scoped>{`
      .react-multi-carousel-item {
        width: 310px !important;
      }
    `}</style>
    <MultiCarousel />
  </div>
</>
```

Comment: is there any way to add css within the TSX file by any chance? If possible, I'd like to not have an external css file. I generally use styled-components for everything else

Comment: A [scoped style tag](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) should work. See my update.